# Only one event fired in RxJava even if multiple observables are subscribed

Tags: android, rx-java

I am trying to understand RxJava. I have written a small piece of code which will upload a list files to firebase server. I have written two observables:
1. ImageUploaderService.java: Upload single file and inform status
2. AllImageUploaderService.java: Create new single file uploader and feed it with one file path to be uploaded.Collect results of all uploaders and inform the caller with links of uploaded files.

My problem is even if each instance of ImageUploaderService is subscribed in AllImageUploaderService, only one event of OnNext is fired. How can I fix it?

AllImageUploaderService.java

```
    public class AllImageUploaderService extends Subscriber<String>{
    private BehaviorSubject<String[]> uploadService;
    private ArrayList<String> uploadedFiles;
    private int expectedCount;
    private int actualCount;

    public Observable<String[]> uploadImages(final String[] fileNames, final StorageReference imagesRef,
        final String[] chosenImage) {
        expectedCount = fileNames.length;
        uploadedFiles = new ArrayList<>(fileNames.length);

        uploadService = BehaviorSubject.create();

        Observable<String[]> observable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String[]>(){
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super String[]> subscriber) {
                for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++) {
                    ImageUploaderService imageUploaderService=new ImageUploaderService();
                    Observable<String> observable= imageUploaderService.uploadImage(fileNames[i],imagesRef,chosenImage[i]);
                    observable.subscribe(AllImageUploaderService.this);
                }
            }
        });
        observable.subscribe(uploadService);
        return uploadService;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        actualCount++;
        if(expectedCount==actualCount) {
            String[] retValue = new String[uploadedFiles.size()];
            uploadedFiles.toArray(retValue);
            uploadService.onNext(retValue);
            uploadService.onCompleted();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Utils.logE(this,"Error",e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(String s) {
        uploadedFiles.add(s);
    }
}
```

ImageUploaderService.java

```
public class ImageUploaderService implements OnFailureListener, OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> {

    private BehaviorSubject<String> uploadSubject;

    public Observable<String> uploadImage(final String fileNames, final StorageReference imagesRef,
        final String chosenImage) {

        uploadSubject = BehaviorSubject.create();
        Observable<String> observable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {               
                StorageReference spaceRef = imagesRef.child(fileNames);
                UploadTask uploadTask = spaceRef.putFile(UriUtil.generatorUri(chosenImage, UriUtil.LOCAL_FILE_SCHEME));
                uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(ImageUploaderService.this);
                uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(ImageUploaderService.this);
            }
        });
        observable.subscribe(uploadSubject);
        return uploadSubject;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        uploadSubject.onError(exception);
        uploadSubject.onCompleted();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
        uploadSubject.onNext(downloadUrl.toString());
        uploadSubject.onCompleted();
    }
}
```

It would be great if you could let me know better approaches to the same.

Comment: Try removing onCompleted. Because onCompleted is a terminal event. No values will be passed on the same subject again.

Comment: @BharathMg that's a very fine way to get observables that never complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to overcomplicate things:

```
public Observable<String> uploadImages(final String[] fileNames, final StorageReference imagesRef,
    final String[] chosenImage) {

    return Observable
        .range(0, fileNames.length)
        .flatMap(i -> new ImageUploaderService()
             .uploadImage(fileNames[i],imagesRef,chosenImage[i]))
}
```

You need it as a collection when everything finishes? `.toList()`.

Also, I'd think that you don't need a subject in the ImageUploaderService:

```
public class ImageUploader implements OnFailureListener, OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> {

  public static Observable<String> uploadImage(final String fileNames, final StorageReference imagesRef,
    final String chosenImage) {

    Observable<String> observable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {               
            ImageUploader uploader = new ImageUploader(subscriber);
            StorageReference spaceRef = imagesRef.child(fileNames);
            UploadTask uploadTask = spaceRef.putFile(UriUtil.generatorUri(chosenImage, UriUtil.LOCAL_FILE_SCHEME));
            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(uploader);
            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(uploader);
        }
    });
    return observable;
  }

  /////////

  private final Subscriber<String> subscriber;

  private ImageUploader(final Subscriber<String> subscriber) {
    this.subscriber = subscriber;
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
    if(subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) return;
    subscriber.onError(exception);
  }

  @Override
  public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
    if(subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) return;
    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
    uploadSubject.onNext(downloadUrl.toString());
    uploadSubject.onCompleted();
  }
}
```

Note, don't emit `onComplete()` after `onError()`, either of those is a terminal state for Observables, and either should be last..

Comment: your code worked for me. Can you please point out what was wrong with my code except for "onComplete() after onError()"?

Comment: You subscribe, then return the original observable. That will cause 2 different subscriptions, and if you don't explicitly plan for it via publish/share/cache, you'll get multiple different subscriptions.